# Run bash script in PHP results in syntax error

Tags: php, bash

I can use the following bash script to start severals terminals at once:

```
for i in 0 1 2 3; do urxvt -name Terminal$i&; done
```

But if I try to run that bash script from a PHP script if fails with error:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
sh: -c: line 0: `for i in 0 1 2 3; do urxvt -name Terminal$i&; done'
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
system('for i in 0 1 2 3; do urxvt -name Terminal$i&; done');
?>
```

This fails, too:

```
<?php
exec('for i in 0 1 2 3; do urxvt -name Terminal$i&; done');
?>
```

Without '&' no errors occurs but I want to start all in background. Escaping the '&' results in an invalid argument error of urxvt.

Any ideas??

Comment: I've seen weird problems with system all the way up to the point where it comes down to using single or double quotes. Try using shell exec instead. http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `;`, the `&` is the termination of the command.

Type `man bash` in your shell and look at "Lists" under the "SHELL GRAMMAR" section.

Comment: that's the deal! Thank a lot!